# Flutter: Make routing child like this in the same scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm currently developing a flutter app on windows desktop and I want to make a navigation child in the same scaffold, i'm tried with PageTransitionSwitcher from animations package, but i'm get failed, how could do this?. thanks

[This is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4uxV.gif)

[This is another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyJ5N.gif)

Comment: if this is your scaffold then you can open the 'end drawer' with full screen

Comment: isn't a drawer .

Comment: like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyJ5N.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing a widget to scaffold on a particular button press, Suppose you want to show Sign in and Sign Up in the same Scaffold their must be two buttons one with the name of Signin and one with the name of sign up so what you can do you can pass SIGNIN Widget on Signin Press while you can passs SignUp Widget on Signup Button Press in the same scaffold That's all.

Comment: I mean, if I tap a card, the next column will be show a information of that card like the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4uxV.gif)

Comment: Yes you can did the same just Use Inkwell on your Card and in Ontap property You can pass the widget class that you want to show in the similar scaffold.